# Movie about an island of mutants

Tags: story-identification, mutant

I remember watching a movie where some shipwreck survivors land on an island full of mutants. Two men get attacked in the water by a mutant and they both start to mutate. One mutates faster than the other. At some point they find a lab in the jungle. The two men who mutated fight each other. Anyone know what I am talking about? Movie was made sometime in the 90s.

Comment: Is it the '96 The Island of Dr. Moreau? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Dr._Moreau_%281996_film%29#Plot

Answer (score 7):

It's not from the 1990s, but this sounds a lot like *[Island of the Fishmen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081467/)* (1979); apparently it was also released in English under the title *Screamers.*

[image: Le Continent des Hommes Poissons]

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_the_Fishmen):

> It is the year 1891 and a military doctor, Lieutenant Claude de Ross (Claudio Cassinelli) a survivor of not one, but two shipwrecks, washes ashore on a mysterious, uncharted Caribbean island along with a handful of convicts. When several of these convicts meet unfortunate ends at the hands of the titular fishmen, Claude and the other survivors flee into the jungle, only to encounter the sadistic Edmond Rackham (Richard Johnson) and his beautiful captive Amanda Marvin (Barbara Bach).
>
> Amanda's father, Professor Ernest Marvin (Joseph Cotten), a once-famed biologist, has discovered a way to transform humans into amphibious creatures and controls their every move. Rackham manipulates Marvin into performing the procedure upon both willing and unwilling participants by assuring him that his work is undertaken for purely scientific and humanitarian motives (Marvin hopes to reduce strain on the world food supply by creating a race of people who can live in the resource-untapped ocean). Having discovered the lost city of Atlantis beneath the waters surrounding the island however, Rackham is in actuality using the half-human monsters to plunder the lost city of its treasures.
>
> Shakira (Beryl Cunningham), a voodoo priestess in the employ of Rackham foretells death and destruction descending upon the island.
>
> The priestess' prophecy is fulfilled as the film ends with Claude and Amanda attempting an escape from a gun-wielding Rackham, a crazed Shakira, uncontrolled fishmen and the very volcano that doomed Atlantis which awakens and threatens to send what unsubmerged landmass remains to oblivion.

Joseph Cotten provides a surprisingly strong performance for what is a very *B* movie.

And if you were worried about Mrs. Ringo being menaced by the titular fish men in the poster, don't worry.  They ended up getting along great.

[image: Barbara and the Fish Men]